# css animation - blurry slideshow reveal from bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to achieve to create a slideshow where the image you first see has a blurry effect then a transition from the bottom slides up and reveals the sharp image.

Currently the blurry image moves up - but I would like only the 'blur' to move up. How could I achieve this? Maybe possible without duplicating the image?

https://jsfiddle.net/78vagwja/6/

**CSS:**

```
#slideshow { 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative; 
}
#slideshow .blur { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    z-index: 10;
    animation: slideUp 1s both linear;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes slideUp {
    0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0); }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3559/3446613250_8569b7d582.jpg">
     <div class="blur">
        <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3559/3446613250_8569b7d582.jpg">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div>
     <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8390/8572035019_0577667f3d.jpg">
     <div class="blur">
      <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8390/8572035019_0577667f3d.jpg">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5582/15049353751_d69ac63ce5.jpg">
     <div class="blur">
      <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5582/15049353751_d69ac63ce5.jpg">
     </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() { 
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .hide()
        .next()
        .show()
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  4000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animate the height on the blur container with overflow hidden.

(simplified to a single image for demonstration at this SO snippet, full version in the jsfiddle bellow)

```css
#slideshow { 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative; 
}
#slideshow .blur { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    animation: slideUp 2s both linear infinite;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    animation-delay: 1s;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}

@keyframes slideUp {
 0% { max-height: 100%}
 100% { max-height:0px}
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
       <div>
         <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8390/8572035019_0577667f3d.jpg">
         <div class="blur">
          <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8390/8572035019_0577667f3d.jpg">
         </div>
       </div>
  
  </div>
```

full example at jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/30fb8L99/4/

Comment: he can also keep the blur on the container ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks! for whatever reason when I tested it didn't work, that's why I took it out. I'll edit my answer with your input for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You can deacrease the height of the `.blur` div instead of moving it and use the image as background to keep its size while the blur disappear:

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .hide()
    .next()
    .show()
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 4000);
```

```css
#slideshow {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#slideshow>div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#slideshow .blur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  z-index: 10;
  animation: slideUp 1s both linear;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    bottom:0;
  }
  100% {
    bottom:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div>
    <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3559/3446613250_8569b7d582.jpg">
    <div class="blur" style="background-image:url(https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3559/3446613250_8569b7d582.jpg)">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8390/8572035019_0577667f3d.jpg">
    <div class="blur" style="background-image:url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8390/8572035019_0577667f3d.jpg)">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5582/15049353751_d69ac63ce5.jpg">
    <div class="blur" style="background-image:url(https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5582/15049353751_d69ac63ce5.jpg)">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```